# Can I restore back to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

Last year, my hard drive pooped out on me, and I had to replace it with a new one. At the time, my mom's boyfriend put Windows 8 Professional on my computer (it's activated, but not legally).

I cannot install Windows 8.1, as the button to install it does nothing.

I cannot install Windows 10 using Microsoft's tool, as that prompts me for a valid Windows 10 product key.

My laptop has a valid Windows 7 Home Premium product key on the bottom of it.

Is there a way I can reset my computer to the factory default of Windows 7 Home Premium? If I can do that, then I won't have to pay $400 for a computer with comparable specs.

If you need the information, my laptop is a HP G62-435DX. I bought it for roughly $450 about 6 years ago, and it's still not a bad machine. The thing holding it back is the invalid installation of Windows 8.

---

#### Edit:

I ordered recovery disks per the comment. It worked.

Comment: @Ramhound how would I format it? Right click and hit "format?"

Comment: [Order a set of HP recovery discs](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c00707939&DocLang=en&docLocale=en_US&jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0005)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first backup your data i.e. from downloads or if you have stored anything there from your c: drive.Then you can revert back to Windows 7 very easily just follow these steps:
1.If you can manage to get your hands on a Windows 7 dvd from your friends or from someone else just boot up from that DVD for installation and insert the key that is mentioned below your laptop when prompted.

2.Otherwise download Windows 7 .iso from the following link https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows7 and burn a DVD or make a bootable USB.

3.Follow on screen instructions just remember to choose custom installation instead of upgrade but before that go to drive options and format your c: drive and proceed.

If you need help creating windows installation media follow:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool
http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/how-to-make-win7-bootable-usb-drive.htm

For installation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pf408Rkc5IA

Don't forget to ask in comments if you face any difficulties.

Edit:As pointed out by Ramhound(Thanks) you need a retail windows to download from the above mentioned link in that case you can order a recovery drive from HP from http://support.hp.com/in-en/document/bph07143 else try to get the installation media from someone else.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry I didn't tried that link and for Youtube link the way the question is asked like installation of Windows 8 by someone else,asking how to format the disk, it appeared to me as he might be uncomfortable installing windows or haven't faced the installation.

Comment: @Ramhound With due respect I wanted to answer everything on this site but it appeared to me that others have already tried that in the comments so, I thought a visual solution might be more appealing for him.

Comment: I already got recovery disks per the comment.

Comment: @DDPWNAGE Glad to hear it worked,please mark an answer or include [solved] in the question to avoid further answers.

Comment: Alright. I honestly forgot this question even existed until tonight. I edited my question.

Comment: Great,doesn't any of the answers seems to resolve your problem?

Comment: I guess they did. The comment with the order link honestly helped the most.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that since the hard disk drive crashed you cannot use the factory reset process (if the laptop had one...)

Since you have the Windows product key you can reinstall but you need a windows 7 DVD. You may ask to the computer manufacturer to send you one. This should not be an issue.

If you can grab an DVD or an ISO file from a friend it may be simpler.

You could also install Windows 10 (the iso can be downloaded from Microsoft) and it will accept your windows 7 product key, however it may be a little too early to adopt windows 10 yet...

Comment: The tool for Windows 10 didn't accept my product key.

Comment: @Ramhound I figured that much. I can't get 8.1, so my solution here is to go back down to 7. It runs 8.